# How to set wms parameter (bbox, width, height, x, y)

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms

I access the geoserver after creating the wms url. Then I use getFeatureInfo to get the information.
How do I set the parameters to get multiple layers info?

what is means width, height, x,y, bbox?

```
var bboxControl = 0.0001;

var bbox = (coordinate[0]-bboxControl) + ',' +  
(coordinate[1]-bboxControl) + ',' +  
(coordinate[0]+bboxControl) + ',' +
(coordinate[1]+bboxControl);

var projection = map.getView().getProjection().getCode();

const parameter = "?SERVICE=WMS
&VERSION=1.1.1
&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo
&FORMAT=image/png
&TRANSPARENT=true" 
+ "&QUERY_LAYERS=" + layers
+ "&LAYERS=" + layers
+ "&exceptions=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage
&INFO_FORMAT=application/json
&FEATURE_COUNT=50
&X=50&Y=50"
+ "&SRS=" + projection
+ "&STYLE=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101"
+ "&BBOX=" + bbox;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: getFeatureInfoUrl + parameter,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(result){
            success(result);
        }           
    });
});
```

This works but not depending on the zoom state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more layers, somewhere in your code you have a list/array named `layers`. Add every layer you want into that.

For your second question check [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html) for GeoServer requests.
But in nutshell:

- BBox means the bounding box. it define the area GeoServer sends the data.
- Width and height define map size returned from GeoServer.